# C# Remove object from JSON with nested property

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this JSON, and I want to delete "delta" section with all nested property. I already use JObject.Remove("delta") but I have this error:

*Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty*

JSON

```
{
  "state": {
    "desired": {
      "optionals": {
        "Variant": "XXXX",
        "Vehicle": {
          "COC00": "AAAA",
          "D0000": "BBBB",
          "D0600": "CCCC"
        }
      }
    },
    "delta": {
      "optionals": {
        "Variant": "XXXX",
        "Vehicle": {
          "COC00": "AAAA",
          "D0000": "BBBB",
          "D0600": "CCCC"
          "D2000": "DDDD",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "timestamp": 1700154568
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Node From JSON dynamically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66310530/remove-node-from-json-dynamically-in-c-sharp)
or this perhaps? [JSON.NET how to remove nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11678520/1390548)

Comment: The above solution is verbose but performant. If this is not a bottleneck you can just deserialize this json to the object with desired shape then serialize it to json.

Comment: I think you're calling Remove on the wrong object. The message says you are calling Remove on an instance of a JProperty. I would expect you are using a JToken as an interface, but probably you are calling `stateProperty.Remove("delta")`. But you would need to call something like `stateProperty.Value.Remove("delta")` (I'm not sure about the exact API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selectToken and then remove the property.

```
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
    JObject header = (JObject)jo.SelectToken("state");
    header.Property("delta").Remove();
    json = jo.ToString();
```